# How to route to different components in Vue router based on query param

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vue-router

I'm using firebase for user authentication. Except for login/signup flows there are 3 flows called [email actions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler?hl=en) - these include reset password, recover email and verify email.

You can customize the URL that Firebase is calling you, but it has the be the same URL for all actions, while the actual action is passed as query param. Here's an example:

```
https://example.com/usermgmt?mode=resetPassword&oobCode=ABC123&apiKey=AIzaSy...&lang=fr
//                          ^^^ from here on starts the dynamic part
```

My question - how can I use Vue router to load different component based on `mode` query param?
I know I can create a single component that will dynamically load one of the other 3 based on the query param, but I'm looking for a cleaner way.

I tried looking for "Vue router based on query params" and only found examples how to pass query param into the component as a prop.

Also looked for examples of implementation of Firebase authentication in Vue, but all of the examples focus just on login and signup.

**EDIT:**
Right now I have a router with this config:

```
  {
    path: '/auth/actions',
    component: () => import('pages/EmailActions.vue'),
    props: (route) => {
      return {
        mode: route.query.mode
      }
    }
  }
```

Then, inside `EmailActions` I have to dynamically show one of 3 components based on `mode` props.
This file is really redundant as it only contains routing code.
What I'd really like to do is something like this in the router config:

```
  {
    path: '/auth/actions',
    children:[
      {
        query: {mode: 'resetPassword'},
        component: () => import ('pages/ResetPassword.vue')
      },
      {
        query: {mode: 'recoverEmail'},
        component: () => import ('pages/RecoverEmail.vue')
      },
      {
        query: {mode: 'verifyEmail'},
        component: () => import ('pages/VerifyEmail.vue')
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: You write "I know I can create a single component that will dynamically load one of the other 3 based on the query param.". What is wrong with this approach? Do you ask for another suggestion or you don't know how to implement it?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec this approach (1) creates additional file with some logic and possibly using dynamic `<component :is="mode">` which doesn't have any added value, and (2) extracts some of the routing logic outside the router.js file, so I can't see all routing in one place.
I can live with it, but looking for a cleaner way, if possible. Edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Can you share your existing code and exactly point out what you would like to change?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I've added my current router config and an example of what I'd like to achive. I hope it is more clear now.